# Can an object with constant acceleration change its direction twice?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

This question is from the book Sears and Zemansky's University Physics.

[image: question]

My answer to the first part of the question is: Yes, in case of free fall when an object is thrown up.

What about the second part? Can it change its direction twice? I cannot think of any situation where this can happen, so probably not. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A change in direction requires $dx/dt$ to be zero (i.e. a stationary point where the velocity is zero).

If $dv/dt$ is constant, then if it is positive, it is possible for $v$ to be initially negative and then go through zero. Or if $dv/dt$ is negative it is possible for $v$ to be initially positive and go through zero.

However, it is *impossible* for the velocity to be zero on two separate occasions unless $dv/dt$ changes sign and thus the acceleration changes with time. Hence it is not possible to change direction twice under uniform acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer to the first part is correct.

As to the second part: You are on the right track. It is not possible to change direction twice, given constant acceleration.

To convince yourself, imagine any general $v-t$ graph - it would be straight line in case of constant acceleration. Change in direction corresponds to $v$ going from  positive to negative or vice versa. Now a straight line graph will not intersect the x-axis more than once. So there you have your answer.

Answer (score -2):

The answer depends on how many dimensions you are working in as well as your definition of acceleration as a vector quantity or a scalar quantity.

If you have 1 dimension, then no, velocity will never go from one direction to the opposite direction and then back to the first direction. In order to change directions the acceleration has to be directed opposite to velocity. Once velocity changes direction the acceleration will be in the same direction so it velocity will not change direction.

If you have >1 dimension and define acceleration as a vector quantity, then an acceleration directed in any direction not parallel or anti-parallel to the velocity will cause the direction to constantly change. For example velocity North and acceleration West will cause an object to constantly change direction towards the West. However this does not mean that the object will be able to reverse its direction twice.

If you have >1 dimension and define acceleration as a scalar quantity, consider constant centripetal acceleration. The velocity changes directions constantly.

Comment: Centripetal acceleration is not constant. It has constant *magnitude*, but not constant *direction*. The first part of your answer is also wrong, because of a similar mistake. Set up a coordinate system so that the constant acceleration is in the $x$ direction, and $y$ and $z$ are any perpendicular directions to complete the 3D coordinate system. The acceleration in the $y$ and $z$ directions is always zero, just like the OP's example of free fall.

Comment: I agree that centripetal acceleration is not a constant rate of change of velocity, but the rate of change of speed is the same, and some people take the rate of change of speed to be called acceleration. In the question it was not specified whether or not acceleration was taken as a vector or scalar quantity. Also, which first part of my answer?

Comment: People who take the rate of change of speed as acceleration are wrong.  Acceleration is a vector.

Comment: What is the rate of change of speed called?